# Return current user

Tags: express, passport.js

I have a small angular/expressjs app that uses passportjs for authentication. Users can log in to the app, when they do I want to show some user data.

I have created a `/profile` express route:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
});
```

Which I call from my Angular front-end. But I can't find anything about returning the current user object. When I log in and call `/profile` My `req.user` is undefined.

Is there a method to return the current user in Expressjs?

Answer (score 0):

The `req.user` in only available/expose when passportjs deserialize is called by `deserializeUser` method.

here example:-

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

For more details [PassportJs Config](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/)